# ExceptionHandler in c# WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a question regarding how exactly this thing works.

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler
{
    private string _pvtMsg;

    public override void handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        //few if else conditions
        if()
        {
        }
        else if
        {
            _pvtMsg = "some value";
        }
        context.Result="Some random value depending upon if else execution";
    }
}
```

Now when `_pvtMsg` is set after that, whenever exception occurs it always have that same value as before.

Does, when I set `_pvtMsg = "a";` in the `else if` condition, the next time an error occurs `_pvtMsg` still have value `"a"`?

Is there only a single instance of `handler` available throughout the lifespan of my application and hence this is happening? Or are there any other reasons? Any documents for reference would be appreciated.

Btw: this handler is registered with the `Register` method of the `WebApiConfig`.

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Since you register an **Instance** of `GlobalExceptionHandler` (with the `new` keyword) `_pvrMsg` will always have the value of the previous (successful) call.

If `_pvrMsg` is critical for whatever you are planning on doing in your `if` block, I'd recommend locking this part of the code to make sure `handle` doesn't execute multiple times at once.

The easiest way to do this would be:

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler
{
    private string _pvtMsg;
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public override void handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            //few if else conditions
            if()
            {
            }
            else if
            {
                _pvtMsg = "some value";
            }
            context.Result="Some random value depending upon if else execution";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to have new value for _pvtMsg for every exception? One way is I can reset the value during Handle method. but other than that is there any way?

Comment: The code is a bit *empty*, so I have no idea what you have planned for `_pvtMsg`.

Comment: In _pvtMsg, I'm adding some custom message in specific exception cases. that's it.

Comment: No I mean, why do you need it when `handler` is called again? You could just use a local variable if you just want to store some text for `context.Result`.

Comment: Yeah.. I guess that makes more sense :-) Thanks.